# how to save binary type in postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

this is php code to save binary data (image,3dmodeling)

To store 3d modeling and textures, it was a DB created to manage them in the first place.

```
use c# system.byte [] datas;
```

```
<?php

$mdata= $_POST['mdata'];
$mmtex= $_POST['mtex'];

$mntex= $_POST['ntext'];
$conn=@pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres password=1234");

$query=  "INSERT INTO tbl_min_mdl VALUES
('001',$mdata,$mmtex,$mntex)";  

$result = pg_query($conn, $query);

echo "$mdata";
//echo "2";
?>
```

When sending and receiving a file, the file is not converted . It seems that I have a wrong understanding of bytea that this method is not working properly now, but I am not sure.

this is table

```
postgres=# select *from tbl_min_mdl;
 mdl_cd | mdl_data | mdl_mt | mdl_nt | mdl_dt | mdl_pos
--------+----------+--------+--------+--------+---------
(0)
```

md_data , mdl_mt , mdl_nt is bytea[] type

what is wrong???

Refer to this
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-binary.html

Comment: **WARNING**: Using the error-suppressing YOLO operator (`@`) obscures problems with your code and makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated. That's a tool of last resort and should only be used in exceptional circumstances. You should display an error message for the user, log a problem, initiate some kind of retry, or all of these things in conjunction.

Comment: **WARNING**: This code is full of [SQL injection bugs](https://bobby-tables.com). Use [`pg_prepare`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php) to create a statement with *placeholder values*, then execute with the data. Even better, use PDO which makes this stuff super easy.

Comment: @tadman thank you very much your warning is appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

byte[] is  not bytea[]  type bytea[] typte

but i don't load bytea file

bytea file is not used escape and decording

```
 mdl_cd | mdl_data | mdl_mt | mdl_nt | mdl_dt
--------+----------+--------+--------+--------
 001    | \x       | \x     | \x     |
 001    | \x       | \x     | \x     |
 001    | \x       | \x     | \x     |
 001    | \x       | \x     | \x     |
 001    | \x       | \x     | \x     |
 001    | \x       | \x     | \x     |
```

it is no work

only load file \x
it was not decording